# Parse [PFInstallation currentInstallation] returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform

I am currently having trouble getting Parse (the push notification service) working on an existing iOS app. Specifically, 
`[PFInstallation currentInstallation]` is always returning a nil value. In my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I set

```
[Parse setApplicationId:parseAppID clientKey:parseClientKey];
```

However, once my `applicationDidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method is called, the code below returns nil for currentInstallation.

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:_deviceToken];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

I am not sure why this is happening just when trying to incorporate this into an existing app. I am doing all the same things I did with a blank app, and Parse worked perfectly there. Note that no errors are being thrown whatsoever. I simply get a nil return on `[PFInstallation currentInstallation]` so nothing is saved.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this happens if you delete an installation on your Parse web console. To fix it, you need to uninstall and reinstall the application on your phone, and it should start working again.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is using "`saveInBackgroundWithBlock`" instead of "`saveInBackouground`" :

```
[currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"success : %d  with error : %@",succeeded,error);
}];
```

This way, you will see if an error is raised.

Besides, in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: method, you should also make a call to

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] != UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
  [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

so that the `applicationDidRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method is called each time you start your application.

Finally, you should make sure you have linked those libraries to your application :

```
- AudioToolbox.framework  
- CFNetwork.framework  
- CoreGraphics.framework  
- CoreLocation.framework  
- libz.dylib  
- MobileCoreServices.framework  
- QuartzCore.framework  
- Security.framework  
- StoreKit.framework  
- SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Comment: Drico, thanks for the help. I did already have my app registering for the different notification types. And I don't think my problem was clear in the original question. The call [PFInstallation currentInstallation] always returns nil. So while I do get an error on the saveInBackground, I don't believe that is the issue. Something is wrong with getting the current installation. I do have all of the libraries attached to my app

Comment: Oh ok, my mistake. Then, what happens if you try this in the didFinishLaunching method :
    [Parse setApplicationId:parseAppID clientKey:parseClientKey];   
    NSLog(@"%@",[PFInstallation currentInstallation]);//directly after the registration